# File Protection in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Can I create a password protected excel file (not workbook/worksheet password protection) using PHPExcel?

I have a linux server and 'COM' class doesn't support linux server. I have no idea how to password protect my excel file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't password protect a file in PHPExcel, that feature simply isn't available. You can only protect cells from being written to, or their style changed.

Comment: Hi. Any other alternative aside from using PHPExcel? Thanks

Comment: Alternatives that will allow you to password protect the actual file? You're limited to [COM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php), [PUNO](http://www.wstech2.net/index.php?do=0a,01,05) and [Ilia's extension](https://github.com/iliaal/php_excel) with [libXL](http://www.libxl.com/)

Comment: Is this option available in 2021?